# After cloning/forking a github repo, is there a way to push only new commits?

Tags: git, github, fork

So what I am trying to do is fork one of my own repositories on Github.  Github does not allow you to do this easily on their site, so I did it this way: http://bitdrift.com/post/4534738938/fork-your-own-project-on-github

This works out great but when I commit the newly forked repository, all of the past commits show up on my Github account rather than my just my initial commit after forking.  Is there a way to make it so that only my new commits on this project/fork are pushed to github?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a new git repository based off of the forked content:

```
# After forking repo:
$ cd /path/to/repo
$ rm -rf .git
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Initial commit (forked from parent/repo)"
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:forked/repo
$ git push origin master
```

After removing and recreating the git repository, GitHub will have no history of past commits and think that everything was done in a large initial commit.